# How to download file from Oracle ucm using web service in Talend job

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

Currently I am working on data migration activities...

I want to download/retrieve file from Oracle ucm using talend open studio tool...

Using soap ui tool,by providing docid/contentid in payload,able to download file(after click on green button,can see XML as response and file will be downloading under attachments tab)..

https://{host}/idcws/GenericSoapPort?wsdl

Used this wsdl link to download using soapui and talend job....

Using same payload in tsoap component, getting XML as response,but how to download physical file in talen job,need suggestions...

1. Tried with tfilefetch component,but no use...

Any suggestions.....

Tried tsoap -->tfilefetch

From tsoap took docurl and passing same to tfilefetch ,after running job,throwing error as url is not correct...

Comment: You say "From tsoap took docurl and passing same to tfilefetch ,after running job,throwing error as url is not correct..."
For this specific problem, it is not clear what went wrong or what you were expecting. Please state what you expected this command to do and what the actual output was.

Additionally, it is not clear what your overall goal is. Do you want to download a single file from UCM? Or do you want to download all files from UCM?

Comment: can you try tHttpRequest?